CSS issue after deploying in aws amplify, Next js app router
The issue is CSS like z-index, fixed, and absolute works on Vercel but not on AWS Amplify, it happened after deployment, I already reverted the commits and re-deployed the version that was working but nothing changed.
The problem is the issue is happening in specific components.
I'm using App-Router, Next: 14.2.3
